# How can I access owncloud files by the owncloud server?

Tags: ubuntu, owncloud

I want to see owncloud files by again the owncloud server machine. Do I need tot install client program to the server machine anyway or is there any other method to reach the owncloud files in the server?

Comment: Owncloud has a web interface.

Answer (score 1):

You can mount the DAV share trough davfs2 that provided a safe read/write access to files without using the owncloud desktop client (that make a useless, in this case, local copy of all files).

To do this you must install the packet davfs2 with

`apt-get install davfs2`

In Debian based systems, or

`yum install davfs2`

in RedHat Based systems.

Then you must edit the file `/etc/davfs2/secrets` adding at the end a line with your login credentials, like:

owncloud.example.org/owncloud/remote.php/webdav

And now you are able to mount the share as a normal filesystem with the `mount` command:

`mount -t davfs owncloud.example.org/owncloud/remote.php/webdav /mnt/`

More options (like permit mount to an unprivileged user) are available, owncloud doc has a good step-by-step guide to do this:
https://doc.owncloud.org/server/7.0/user_manual/files/files.html#creating-webdav-mounts-on-the-linux-command-line

It's true that you can directly access your file in the data/ dir but it's not the cleanest way (especially if you want edit/add/delete them).

Comment: link-only answers are frowned upon and are not really that helpful.

Comment: @Ramhound sorry, I'm new here and maybe I misunderstood the best practices. The link point to a step-by-step guide to mount an owncloud share with davfs2, so I simply avoided to fill the page with a log copy-paste. Maybe best practices say a different thing? Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the help center so you don't make preventable mistakes.  Before submitting an answer to an existing age question, be sure the answer is absolutely exceptional, because I personally hold new answers to old questions to a higher standard then answers to new questions.  Be sure the answer to this existing question, is adding something unique, which hasn't already been said by somebody else.  Just adding your comments isn't helpful, if you want to add comments to those questions, submit comments.

Comment: @Ramhound reading again my answer it looks too a "just search somewhere on doc", so I edited to clarify. About the "old question" I noticed the age only later (I found it jumping around on open questions about owncloud). Finally, I think that the answer is pertinent and provide a proper way to mount owncloud share with safe read/write support without using the desktop client, as originally asked (I don't know if you looked in technical details). Anyway thanks for clarifications :)

Comment: When an answer contains a link, without any quote blocks, and it's not a download I make that comment.  "Step by Step guide" but that guide doesn't exist here at Superuser

Comment: So the problem is that it is an external link to official owncloud doc? A one-hundred lines of quote is better in these cases?

Comment: provide a summary.  It's 9 steps.... That's like 25 lines at most

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

just access the **web-interface** with this adress/link:
**http://localhost/owncloud** or eventual https://localhost/owncloud

if you want to "take a look behind the scenes" (or haven't installed a desktop environment) you can start your **file-manager** and look for **/var/www/owncloud/data/*"username"*** (for the case you are running an apache-server)!

Answer (score -1):

use ssh to access the server, find the install directory and have fun with the files. 
if a apache is installed you can find the the directory in the apache conf but normaly it should be under /var/www/
you can also use winscp to acces the server

Comment: This is plain false and dangerous. You shouldn't even have read permissions to ownclouds datafolder, and Ieven if youd do and change anything, the application will not be aware of it, the database entries will not be updated etc.

Comment: true , it is dangerous to modify the owncloud files. I would leave them as they are.

Answer (score -1):

No problem, you can open a terminal from the graphical interface of the server if you have physical access to it and run nautilus with sudo permissions and then navigate to the directory where you have the filesystem mounted.

Answer (score -2):

If you use a apache the main directory for owncloud is 
/var/www/html or /var/www/html/owcloud

There are store all files on your owncloud server.